# Is it possible to use pip to install a package from a private GitHub repository?

Tags: python, git, github, pip

I am trying to install a Python package from a private GitHub repository. For a public repository, I can issue the following command which works fine:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/django/django.git
```

However, if I try this for a private repository:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/echweb/echweb-utils.git
```

I get the following output:

```
Downloading/unpacking git+git://github.com/echweb/echweb-utils.git
Cloning Git repository git://github.com/echweb/echweb-utils.git to /var/folders/cB/cB85g9P7HM4jcPn7nrvWRU+++TI/-Tmp-/pip-VRsIoo-build
Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/git clone git://github.com/echweb/echweb-utils.git /var/folders/cB/cB85g9P7HM4jcPn7nrvWRU+++TI/-Tmp-/pip-VRsIoo-build:
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Cloning into /var/folders/cB/cB85g9P7HM4jcPn7nrvWRU+++TI/-Tmp-/pip-VRsIoo-build...

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/local/bin/git clone git://github.com/echweb/echweb-utils.git /var/folders/cB/cB85g9P7HM4jcPn7nrvWRU+++TI/-Tmp-/pip-VRsIoo-build failed with error code 128
```

I guess this is because I am trying to access a private repository without providing any authentication. I therefore tried to use Git + `ssh` hoping that pip would use my SSH public key to authenticate:

```
pip install git+ssh://github.com/echweb/echweb-utils.git
```

This gives the following output:

```
Downloading/unpacking git+ssh://github.com/echweb/echweb-utils.git
Cloning Git repository ssh://github.com/echweb/echweb-utils.git to /var/folders/cB/cB85g9P7HM4jcPn7nrvWRU+++TI/-Tmp-/pip-DQB8s4-build
Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/git clone ssh://github.com/echweb/echweb-utils.git /var/folders/cB/cB85g9P7HM4jcPn7nrvWRU+++TI/-Tmp-/pip-DQB8s4-build:
Cloning into /var/folders/cB/cB85g9P7HM4jcPn7nrvWRU+++TI/-Tmp-/pip-DQB8s4-build...

Permission denied (publickey).

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/local/bin/git clone ssh://github.com/echweb/echweb-utils.git /var/folders/cB/cB85g9P7HM4jcPn7nrvWRU+++TI/-Tmp-/pip-DQB8s4-build failed with error code 128
```

Is what I am trying to achieve even possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: It certainly isn't the correct answer, but cloning the repo manually then pointing pip to localhost instead of github will get you past this if you're just trying to be productive.

Comment: @nmicheals That's what I've done so far, but I need to put this into requirements files for deployment across many web sites all with separate virtualenvs.

Comment: Just to he sure: you've already set up ssh key support on github, right? If that's definitely not working.... Have you tried using git+git://user:pass@github.com/.... as the URI?

Comment: Try using `eval $(ssh-agent); ssh-add ~/.ssh/github_id_rsa` and then run pip installs following https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git

Answer (score 611, accepted):

You can use the `git+ssh` URI scheme, but you *must* set a username. Notice the **`git@`** part in the URI:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/echweb/echweb-utils.git
```

Also read about [deploy keys](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/managing-deploy-keys).

PS: In my installation, the "git+ssh" URI scheme works only with "editable" requirements:

```
pip install -e URI#egg=EggName
```

**Remember**: Change the `:` character that `git remote -v` prints to a `/` character before using the remote's address in the `pip` command:

```bash
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:echweb/echweb-utils.git (fetch)
#                     ^ change this to a '/' character
```

If you forget, you will get this error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com:echweb:
         nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I was just missing the git@ part. Incidentally the command 'pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/echweb/echweb-utils.git' worked, I did not require the -e switch.

Comment: you can also use an .ssh/config file to set the proper username

Comment: This used to be working for me but now isn't, I'm even using the correct `git+ssh://git@github.com/echweb/echweb-utils.git` scheme in my requirements file. I opened a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883430/trouble-installing-private-github-repository-using-pip. Any help would be great.

Comment: This is what I need to do with our in-house (corporate) github deployment. Is the "git@" part documented anywhere? I spent some time looking before I found your post; it definitely doesn't seem to be a part of pip documentation. I'm curious. And thank you!

Comment: It's not pip-specific, so it not part of pip doc. I know that because have strong knowledge in unix/ssh/git and setup repo hostings in pre-github(and pre-git) era.

"git@" part can be found in github "SSH clone URL" field for any repo in which you have write access.

Comment: @m.kocikowski "git@" is part of the URL. URLs are standard, and not pip-specific: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986

Comment: Does it matter what username you use?

Comment: Yes, you should use only "git" username for ssh access to github and most other VCS hostings. All files saved under one system user (git) and permissions managed not by OS, but by software internally. To distinguish between users special ssh-daemon uses key, which was used for auth.

Comment: Perfect. Putting `git+ssh://git@github.com/echweb/echweb-utils.git` into `requirements.txt` works too, which is awesome.

Comment: If you need to run this from a script (eg: for deployment...), you can specify which SSH key to use with the environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-deploy-key"`

Comment: "Could not detect requirement name, please specify one with #egg="

Comment: If you want to install from a specific branch: `pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/echweb/echweb-utils.git@branch-name`

Comment: What is the purpose of giving #egg=EggName ?

Comment: Hmmm, not sure if it's still actual.

Before `wheels`, there were `eggs` in the world of Python, but as of now, it's most likely totally outdated.

Comment: thank you! i wasn't adding the `git@` and it was using the wrong username.

Answer (score 100):

As an additional technique, if you have the private repository cloned locally, you can do:

```
pip install git+file://c:/repo/directory
```

More modernly, you can just do this (and the `-e` will mean you don't have to commit changes before they're reflected):

```
pip install -e C:\repo\directory
```

Comment: This was quite helpful. Apparently, local changes have to be git-commit'd before they can be installed via pip.

Comment: That's true - it's pulling it from the git repository (in .git), NOT the working copies of the files.

Answer (score 56):

You can do it directly with the HTTPS URL like this:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/username/repo.git
```

This also works just appending that line in the requirements.txt in a [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) project, for instance.

Comment: For private repos, though, this will trigger a username/password prompt on the console, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Note: GitHub have disabled password authentication, so you _won't_ see a password prompt. But pip has also disabled stdout passthrough from sub-commands, so you also can't use an SSH key with a password, unless it's already unlocked in your ssh-agent. This is likely the case on Mac or Linux, but almost certainly not on Windows. If you're on Windows and have the new [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager) installed, it will automatically authenticate you for https URLs in a way which doesn't break pip. So https is now the smoothest option on Windows.

Comment: For private repos you can create a personal access token with read access to the private repo and add that to the https url like so:
```pip install git+https://github_pat_qwerty12345@github.com/username/repo.git```
and it will authenticate

Answer (score 44):

It also works with [Bitbucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket):

```
pip install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/username/projectname.git
```

Pip will use your SSH keys in this case.

Answer (score 34):

I found it much easier to use tokens than SSH keys. I couldn't find much good documentation on this, so I came across this solution mainly through trial and error. Further, installing from pip and setuptools have some subtle differences; but this way should work for both.

GitHub don't (currently, as of August 2016) offer an easy way to get the zip / tarball of private repositories. So you need to tell setuptools that you're pointing to a Git repository:

```
from setuptools import setup
import os
# Get the deploy key from https://help.github.com/articles/git-automation-with-oauth-tokens/
github_token = os.environ['GITHUB_TOKEN']

setup(
    # ...
    install_requires='package',
    dependency_links = [
    'git+https://{github_token}@github.com/user/{package}.git/@{version}#egg={package}-0'
        .format(github_token=github_token, package=package, version=master)
        ]
```

A couple of notes here:

- For private repositories, you need to authenticate with GitHub; the simplest way I found is to create an [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) token, drop that into your environment, and then include it with the URL
- You need to include *some* version number (here is `0`) at the end of the link, even if there's isn't any package on [PyPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Package_Index). This has to be a actual number, not a word.
- You need to preface with `git+` to tell setuptools it's to clone the repository, rather than pointing at a zip / tarball
- `version` can be a branch, a tag, or a commit hash
- You need to supply `--process-dependency-links` if installing from pip

Comment: Note `setup.py` should not contain concrete dependencies, only abstract ones. This is specifying a concrete dependency on `setup.py`.

Comment: With the release of pip version 19.0, --process-dependency-links option is deprecated.

Answer (score 28):

I figured out a way to automagically 'pip install' a GitLab private repository that requires no password prompt. This approach uses GitLab "Deploy Keys" and an SSH configuration file, so you can deploy using keys other than your personal SSH keys (in my case, for use by a 'bot). Perhaps someone kind soul can verify using GitHub.

#### Create a New SSH key:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "GitLab_Robot_Deploy_Key"
```

The file should show up as `~/.ssh/GitLab_Robot_Deploy_Key` and `~/.ssh/GitLab_Robot_Deploy_Key.pub`.

Copy and paste the contents of the `~/.ssh/GitLab_Robot_Deploy_Key.pub` file into the GitLab "Deploy Keys" dialog.

#### Test the New Deploy Key

The following command tells SSH to use your new deploy key to set up the connection. On success, you should get the message: "Welcome to GitLab, UserName!"

```
ssh -T -i ~/.ssh/GitLab_Robot_Deploy_Key git@gitlab.mycorp.com
```

#### Create the SSH Configuration File

Next, use an editor to create a `~/.ssh/config` file. Add the following contents. The 'Host' value can be anything you want (just remember it, because you'll be using it later). The HostName is the URL to your GitLab instance. The IdentifyFile is path to the SSH key file you created in the first step.

```
Host GitLab
  HostName gitlab.mycorp.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/GitLab_Robot_Deploy_Key
```

#### Point SSH to the Configuration file

[oxyum gave us](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830856/is-it-possible-to-use-pip-to-install-a-package-from-a-private-github-repository/4837571#4837571) the recipe for using pip with SSH:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@gitlab.mycorp.com/my_name/my_repo.git
```

We just need to modify it a bit to make SSH use our new Deploy Key. We do that by pointing SSH to the Host entry in the SSH configuration file. Just replace the 'gitlab.mycorp.com' in the command to the host name we used in the SSH configuration file:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@GitLab/my_name/my_repo.git
```

The package should now install without any password prompt.

[Reference A](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html) 
[Reference B](http://snipe.net/2013/04/multiple-github-deploy-keys-single-server/)

Answer (score 21):

If you want to install dependencies from a requirements file within a CI server, you can do this:

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache'
echo "protocol=https
host=example.com
username=${GIT_USER}
password=${GIT_PASS}
" | git credential approve
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

In my case, I used `GIT_USER=gitlab-ci-token` and `GIT_PASS=${CI_JOB_TOKEN}`.

This method has a clear advantage. You have a single requirements file which contains all of your dependencies.

Comment: I am wondering if I can do the same in Github , like github has GITHUB_TOKEN as default token attached to each repo just like in gitlab CI_JOB_TOKEN but I am not sure of user in Github ?

Comment: Providing username+password the first time, and doing one time `git config --global credential.helper 'store'` solved my problem.

Comment: This now fails with `Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.`

Answer (score 19):

My case was kind of more complicated than most of the ones described in the answers. I was the owner of two private repositories `repo_A` and `repo_B` in a Github organization and needed to `pip install repo_A` during the `python` unittests of `repo_B`, [as a Github action](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/guides/building-and-testing-python).

Steps I followed to solve this task:

- Created a [Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token) for my account. As for its permissions, I only needed to keep the default ones, .i.e. *repo - Full control of private repositories*.
- Created a [repository secret](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets) under `repo_B`, pasted my Personal Access Token in there and named it `PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN`. **This was important** because, unlike the solution proposed by [Jamie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63416597/6204860), I didn't need to explicitly expose my precious raw Personal Access Token inside the github action `.yml` file.
- Finally, `pip install` the package from source via HTTPS (**not** SSH) as follows:

```sh
export PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN=${{ secrets.PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN }}

pip install git+https://${PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}@github.com/MY_ORG_NAME/repo_A.git
```

Comment: Would SSH keys have worked in this case as well?

Comment: @MarcelWilson I would expect it to work. However, using an access token over SSH keys comes with the additional benefit of being able to adjust the access level of the token. This might be very useful when using Github `actions` (workflows) to `pip install` a private repo during unittesting of another shared repo where you don't want to share your SSH keys with others, not even as a Github`secret`. Tl;dr, access tokens are less permissive as far as I can tell.

Comment: @MarcelWilson - what pcko1 said, for me, the primary plus of token is that I can create and destroy tokens as needed without mucking with my personal dev settings

Comment: To use ssh, one would have to use git+ssh instead of git+https though no need to provide a personal access token in this case.

Answer (score 18):

The syntax for the requirements file is given here:

https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#requirements-file-format

So for example, use:

```
-e git+http://github.com/rwillmer/django-behave#egg=django-behave
```

if you want the source to stick around after installation.

Or just

```
git+http://github.com/rwillmer/django-behave#egg=django-behave
```

if you just want it to be installed.

Comment: The URL for the requirements file syntax has changed. The new URL is: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#requirements-file-format

Comment: Is the `egg` a hard requirement? I'm trying to install via ssh a private python package with a deploy key but keep getting a response of `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128`.

Answer (score 18):

If you need to do this in, say, a command line one-liner, it's also possible. I was able to do this for deployment on Google Colab:

1. Create a Personal Access Token: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token
2. Run: `pip install git+https://<USERNAME>:<PERSONAL ACCESS TOKEN>@github.com/<ACCOUNT>/<REPOSITORY>.git`

Comment: You might add a comment noting that your access token will be in plaintext and accessible to anyone who can read the pip configuration.

Comment: Also, now that I think about it, your answer is kind of a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39254921/241211) from 4 years ago.

Answer (score 9):

You can also install a private repository dependency via [git+https://github.com/...](http://git+https://github.com/...) URL by providing login credentials (login and password, or deploy token) for [curl](https://git-scm.com/book/uz/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#Networking) with the `.netrc` file:

```sh
echo "machine github.com login ei-grad password mypasswordshouldbehere" > ~/.netrc
pip install "git+https://github.com/ei-grad/my_private_repo.git#egg=my_private_repo"
```

Answer (score 7):

When I was installing from GitHub I was able to use:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/<username>/<projectname>.git#egg=<eggname>
```

But, since I had to run pip as `sudo`, the SSH keys were not working with GitHub any more, and "git clone" failed on "Permission denied (publickey)". Using `git+https` allowed me to run the command as sudo, and have GitHub ask me for my user/password.

```
sudo pip install git+https://github.com/<username>/<projectname>.git#egg=<eggname>
```

Comment: Do other user accounts need to access your project? If not, have you discovered [nerdwaller's suggestion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830856/#comment55105837_27901245)

Comment: Is the `egg` a hard requirement? I'm trying to install via ssh a private python package with a deploy key but keep getting a response of `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128`.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to use SSH, you could add the username and password in the HTTPS URL.

The code below assumes that you have a file called "pass" in the working directory that contains your password.

```sh
export PASS=$(cat pass)
pip install git+https://<username>:$PASS@github.com/echweb/echweb-utils.git
```

Comment: Does this stamp your password in plaintext into some configuration file?

Answer (score 4):

If you have your own library/package on GitHub, GitLab, etc., you have to add a tag to commit with a concrete version of the library, for example, v2.0, and then you can install your package:

```
pip install git+ssh://link/name/repo.git@v2.0
```

This works for me. Other solutions haven't worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Just copy the remote from the original `git clone` command (or from `git remote -v`). You will get something like this:

- **Bitbucket:** `git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org:your_account/my_pro.git`
- **GitHub:** `git+ssh://git@github.com:your_account/my_pro.git`

Next, you need to replace **`:`** with **`/`** next to the domain name.

So install using:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/your_account/my_pro.git
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"copy git clone command"*? Do you mean *"copy using the 'git clone' command"*? Or *"copy the 'git clone' command"*? Or something else? (Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58689622/edit), not here in comments (as appropriate). Thanks in advance.).

Comment: if you visit the repository website and press the clone button on top both BB and github will show you a clone command for the repo.

Answer (score 0):

[oxyum's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4837571/1126085) solution is OK for this answer. I just want to point out that you need to be careful if you are installing using `sudo` as the keys must be stored for root too (for example, `/root/.ssh`).

Then you can type

```
sudo pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/echweb/echweb-utils.git
```

Comment: Easy solution: don't instal with sudo. Instead use the `--user` flag or a virtualenv.

Answer (score -1):

You may try

```
pip install git+git@gitlab.mycorp.com/my_name/my_repo.git
```

without `ssh:...`. That works for me.

Comment: OP requested github.

Comment: I found it helpful.