# Is it possible to use pip to install a package over ssh in a self-hosted gitlab?

Tags: ssh, pip, gitlab

I have a self-hosted gitlab and I would like to install a package hosted there using ssh.

I tried:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@<my_domain>:se7entyse7en/<project_name>.git
```

Here's the output:

```
Downloading/unpacking git+ssh://git@<my_domain>:se7entyse7en/<project_name>.git
Cloning ssh://git@<my_domain>:se7entyse7en/<project_name>.git to /var/folders/3r/v7swlvdn2p7_wyh9wj90td2m0000gn/T/pip-4_JdRU-build
ssh: Could not resolve hostname <my_domain>:se7entyse7en: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

**Update**:

I tried to upload it on gitlab.com and after having uploaded the repo I tried to install it by running:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@gitlab.com:loumarvincaraig/<project_name>.git
```

but the nothing changed. In particular here's the content of `pip.log`:

---

```
/Users/se7entyse7en/Envs/test/bin/pip run on Mon Nov 17 22:14:51 2014
Downloading/unpacking git+ssh://git@gitlab.com:loumarvincaraig/<project_name>.git

Cloning ssh://git@gitlab.com:loumarvincaraig/<project_name>.git to /var/folders/3r/v7swlvdn2p7_wyh9wj90td2m0000gn/T/pip-91JVFi-build

Found command 'git' at '/usr/local/bin/git'
Running command /usr/local/bin/git clone -q ssh://git@gitlab.com:loumarvincaraig/<project_name>.git /var/folders/3r/v7swlvdn2p7_wyh9wj90td2m0000gn/T/pip-91JVFi-build
Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/git clone -q ssh://git@gitlab.com:loumarvincaraig/<project_name>.git /var/folders/3r/v7swlvdn2p7_wyh9wj90td2m0000gn/T/pip-91JVFi-build:
```

---

```
Cleaning up...

Command /usr/local/bin/git clone -q ssh://git@gitlab.com:loumarvincaraig/<project_name>.git /var/folders/3r/v7swlvdn2p7_wyh9wj90td2m0000gn/T/pip-91JVFi-build failed with error code 128 in None

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/se7entyse7en/Envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 134, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/Users/se7entyse7en/Envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 236, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
File "/Users/se7entyse7en/Envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1092, in prepare_files
self.unpack_url(url, location, self.is_download)
File "/Users/se7entyse7en/Envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1231, in unpack_url
return unpack_vcs_link(link, loc, only_download)
File "/Users/se7entyse7en/Envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 410, in unpack_vcs_link
vcs_backend.unpack(location)
File "/Users/se7entyse7en/Envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/vcs/__init__.py", line 240, in unpack
self.obtain(location)
File "/Users/se7entyse7en/Envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/vcs/git.py", line 111, in obtain
call_subprocess([self.cmd, 'clone', '-q', url, dest])
File "/Users/se7entyse7en/Envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 670, in call_subprocess
% (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command /usr/local/bin/git clone -q ssh://git@gitlab.com:loumarvincaraig/<project_name>.git /var/folders/3r/v7swlvdn2p7_wyh9wj90td2m0000gn/T/pip-91JVFi-build failed with error code 128 in None
```

Comment: Obvious question, but is your SSH working for git push? Have you tried on gitlab.com, where we can all reproduce?

Comment: yeah ssh is working for git push. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I don't know why, but by running the following command it worked (slash instead of : after `<my_domain>`):

```
pip install git+ssh://git@<my_domain>/se7entyse7en/<project_name>.git
#                                    ^
#                             slash instead of :
```

Comment: Anyone who know the reason?

Comment: @guemues [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4837571/4594973) has additional info on that detail.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. This is the default use:

`pip install git+ssh://git@<my_domain>:22/<project_group>/<project_name>.git`

The use of the colon by itself implies the default ssh port number 22. Because you can control the port number of your server, the port number could be different. Git enables customisation by not providing `:22/` or `/` only.