# Pip, Git and ssh key with custom path

Tags: python, git, ssh, pip

Based on the following question ([Is it possible to use pip to install a package from a private github repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830856/is-it-possible-to-use-pip-to-install-a-package-from-a-private-github-repository)), I try to connect to pip a git repository via ssh.

My key is in a custom path. I try to import it without success, always ending with

```
Command /usr/bin/git clone -q ssh://git@bitbucket.org:<user>/<repo>.git /tmp/pip-rYrupA-build failed with error code 128 in None
```

I tried to log with

```
pip install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org:<user>/<repo>.git -i /path/to/id_rsa
```

without success. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, found the answer: Bitbuckets gives a ssh link to the repository formatted as

```
git@bitbucket.org:<user>/<repo>.git
```

The problem is due to the ":", which should be replaced by "/":

```
git@bitbucket.org/<user>/<repo>.git
```