# pip install --editable with a VCS url

Tags: python, git, package, pip

In `man pip` it says under `--editable <path/url>`,

> Install a project in editable mode (i.e.  setuptools "develop mode")
>   from a local project path or a VCS url

What does that mean? Can I give it a repo branch on Github, and it'll go get it and install it and keep it updated as the branch changes?

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to install package from git repo [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-github-repo-branch?rq=1)

`-e` or `--editable` is little bit different, it is used, as stated in docs, for setuptools's [development mode](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html?highlight=develop%20mode#development-mode). It makes installed packages editable.

Yes you can give it link to github. Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830856/is-it-possible-to-use-pip-to-install-a-package-from-a-private-github-repository#4837571) for more info. But this link will only work if this repository contains `setup.py` with all installation instructions. And this package will be updated when you call

```
pip install -U -e <url>
```

But only if version of package in `setup.py` is higher than the one in your environment.

You can forcefully reinstall this package if you need to, when source did change but version didn't.

```
pip install -I -e <url>
```

Comment: Not sure, but it seems now `pip install -U ...` will upgrade the installation to the newest commit even if the version hasn't changed. The version shown has a bit of the commit SHA appended to it.

Comment: Agree pip install -U <url> will update the package with latest commit