# App Engine Flexible - requirements.txt include GCP repository

Tags: python, git, google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible, requirements.txt

I am trying to set up an application running in a python 3 App Engine Flexible environment. I have an app.yaml file:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT application:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

I have a requirements.txt listing some packages my app needs:

```
Flask==0.12
gunicorn==19.7.1
...
```

I also have a common functions package that is located in a GCP source respository (git). I don't want to host it publicly on PyPi. Is it possible to still include it as a requirement? Something like:

```
git+https://source.developers.google.com/p/app/r/common
```

Using the above ask for a username and password when I try it on my local machine, even though I have a helper set up:

```
git config credential.helper gcloud.sh
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830856/is-it-possible-to-use-pip-to-install-a-package-from-a-private-github-repository help?

Comment: git+ssh:// always hangs, with or without git@, with or without editable mode. Presumably ssh isn't available to source repos. git+git:// is the same. GitHub have obviously enabled this service separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `-i http://yourhost.com --trusted-host yourhost.com` flags to `requirements.txt` file.