# Use private repository for Python in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pip

I would like to use my own package located in private repository.

Actually, i use requirements.txt file to install dependencies in my Python AppEngine.

However, i don't understand where do I have to add my private dependency.

Thanks

Comment: standard or flexible env?

Comment: Did you try adding the `extra-index-url` in the requirements? E.g. `pypkg==1.0 --extra-index-url=https://my.pypi.org`.

Comment: flexible env for to used Python 3

Comment: Thanks hoefling. I can try. But how i use authorisation key ?

Comment: Are you asking for using third-party libraries in your Google App Engine app? If so it is possible in [GAE](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27). In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29681061/9908267) answer the steps how to do is explained. Is this what you'd like to manage?

Comment: any luck with this ? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the private package to the `requirements.txt` by using the `git+ssh` protocol. Better instructions can be found here: [Is it possible to use pip to install a package from a private github repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830856/is-it-possible-to-use-pip-to-install-a-package-from-a-private-github-repository)

However, I am not sure how GAE handles private keys required to access the package. If GAE only copies the `lib` directory from the AppEngine project repository without other magical operations upon deployment, it should work. If AppEngine only uses the `lib` dependencies to collect the names of the packages and then does something funny by itself, I guess you would be out of luck, if there does not exist a way to give credentials to the AppEngine for deployment.

I am unable to test this now, but will update as soon as I have.