# Azure functions use ssh to access private github repo

Tags: python, azure, github, ssh, azure-functions

I am migrating quite some projects from local servers to Azure functions. In these projects we use our own created Python modules which we are hosting on **private** GitHub repo. When developing locally or on a Ubuntu server, we can add the ssh-key to the GitHub repo and we can do:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/org-name/package-name.git
```

to install our own modules.

But how would we do this on an Azure functions where we have this in our `requirements.txt`. I am not sure how to add ssh to our function app.

Or is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[-e] git+ssh://git.example.com/MyProject#egg=MyProject` in `requirements.txt`.

Reference to [Requirements File Format](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format).

Comment: Does that mean that the project has to be local? If it is, than that will not work. The project is hosted on github and maintained quite often.

Comment: No, `requirements.txt` would work after deploying to azure. Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python

Comment: Can you explain how azure would have access to our private repository then with ssh? Are you sure this will work?

Comment: That would take some time for testing... Here is an issue may enlighten you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53181349/can-i-use-pip-to-install-a-package-from-a-private-vsts-repository