# How to create installer for python application?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-packaging, python-install

I have developed an application which has multiple file and some dependent libraries such as bacpypes, requests, rdflib etc.

I want to create an installer which will install all the packages along with the application so that the user need not to download the packages separately.

Currently to deploy the application, i am copying source code, installing libraries using pip or external download.

Comment: https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: You could also pip install from Github - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830856/is-it-possible-to-use-pip-to-install-a-package-from-a-private-github-repository

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider [SetupTools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html).

> From the introduction to `SetupTools`: `Setuptools` is a collection of
>   enhancements to the Python `distutils` that allow developers to more
>   easily build and distribute Python packages, especially ones that have
>   dependencies on other packages.

Answer (score 0):

Use this - [Pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/)

> PyInstaller freezes (packages) Python applications into
> stand-alone executables, under Windows, GNU/Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD,
> Solaris and AIX.
>
> PyInstaller’s main advantages over similar tools are that PyInstaller
> works with Python 3.5—3.7, it builds smaller executables thanks to
> transparent compression, it is fully multi-platform, and use the OS
> support to load the dynamic libraries, thus ensuring full
> compatibility.