# pull latest changes when pip installing from github

Tags: python, git, pip, requirements.txt

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4837571/2899096), I've added to my package's `requirements.txt` file a github source:

```
-e git+ssh://git@github.com/blabla/blabla_project.git#egg=blabla_project
```

Problem is, whenever the are changes in blabla project, I have to specifically go to it's directory and run `git pull` to get them.

I'd like blabla_project to update automatically when I run `git pull` on my project, or at least when I run `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Is there a way to do either of these things?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bpip%5D+%5Brequirements.txt%5D+update

Comment: `pip install -U -r requirements.txt`