# Simple way to pip install a private Github repo?

Tags: python-3.x, git, github, pip

I know I can set up SSH and do all sorts of shenanigans, but I'm doing this on an Amazon EC2 instance, so I really just want to keep everything as fool proof as possible. Is there any dirt simple quick way to pip install a private github repo, have it ask for my credentials in a way that's secure (not logged), and go along my merry way? The documentation I've found on the subject thus far seems excessively obtuse given the popularity of both pip and github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really, if you want a secure and easy way to do it, SSH is the way to go (as stated by Romeo). While daunting at first due to the sheer amount of information, implementing it is actually super easy, and actually less complex than other alternatives. This video walks through it step by step:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQDFBd5NFA8

The only thing that's the least bit tricky, if you're doing this on some sort of ec2 instance, you might need to use a text editor like nano to view the public key so you can copy it. just do

```
nano ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

then, because its long, you can enable code wrapping by

```
press esc, release esc, shift+4
```

that will allow you to, view the whole ssh public key so you can easily copy it on the machine where you're setting everything up

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830856/is-it-possible-to-use-pip-to-install-a-package-from-a-private-github-repository). But to be honest I'd rather create a ssh key pair, protect it with a password, copy the public key to github and pull via ssh - sounds much more secure to me

```sh
export PASS=$(cat pass)
pip install git+https://<username>:$PASS@github.com/echweb/echweb-utils.git
```