# How to import a private package in PyFlink

Tags: python, apache-flink, pyflink

I'm trying to import a private package in PyFlink.

I have an UDF that needs to call a function in a private library (not available through pip install because the repo is private).

Therefore I can't use something like this:

```
table_env.set_python_requirements(requirements_file_path="/path/to/requirements.txt")
```

How to import this private package to access it in my PyFlink UDF function ?

Comment: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/private-python-packages.html and https://stackoverflow.com/q/4830856/2000823

Comment: That's right. I'm using a PyFlink in the https://github.com/pyflink/playgrounds Docker image. I was looking if there was a PyFlink specific way of doing this but I think I'll have no choice to build some custom images with those included. 
Thanks again !