# pip install custom package from BitBucket with SSH without entering SSH password

Tags: python, ssh, pip, bitbucket

I am trying to use `pip install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/my_org/my_package_repo.git` to install a custom-made python package (shared by multiple applications) from BitBucket WITHOUT having to enter the SSH password.

There seems to be a lot of good information in one of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830856/is-it-possible-to-use-pip-to-install-a-package-from-a-private-github-repository) for doing this in GitLab, etc.  There's also some solid supporting information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830856/is-it-possible-to-use-pip-to-install-a-package-from-a-private-github-repository/4837571#4837571).

I've already setup an SSH key between my local Mac and this BitBucket account.  I'm able to push/pull code all the time to/from this account without having to re-enter the SSH password.  Why is the `pip install` command requiring the password, when it's not required by `git` commands?  Is there a way around this with BitBucket and the setup I've described?

### Update

When I run the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -vvv' pip install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/my_org/my_package_repo.git` command recommended in the comments, I get the following (sanitized) response:

```
Collecting git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/my_org/my_package_repo.git
  Cloning ssh://git@bitbucket.org/my_org/my_package_repo.git to /private/var/folders/hh/v8z4pvkn3kl14c9ty827578c0000gq/T/pip-req-build-i9q_8b83
  Running command git clone -q ssh://git@bitbucket.org/my_org/my_package_repo.git /private/var/folders/hh/v8z4pvkn3kl14c9ty827578c0000gq/T/pip-req-build-i9q_8b83
  OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
  debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/username/.ssh/config
  debug1: /Users/username/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
  debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
  debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
  debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org port 22.
  debug1: Connection established.
  debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
  debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
  debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
  debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
  debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
  debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
  debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
  debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
  debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
  debug1: identity file /Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
  debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
  debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version conker_a7531beec7 c7d1b850e369
  debug1: no match: conker_a7531beec7 c7d1b850e369
  debug3: fd 7 is O_NONBLOCK
  debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git'
  debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts"
  debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts:3
  debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from bitbucket.org
  debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
  debug3: send packet: type 20
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
  debug3: receive packet: type 20
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
  debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
  debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
  debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
  debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
  debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
  debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
  debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
  debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
  debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
  debug2: languages ctos:
  debug2: languages stoc:
  debug2: first_kex_follows 0
  debug2: reserved 0
  debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
  debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-s
  debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss
  debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
  debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
  debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
  debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
  debug2: compression ctos: none
  debug2: compression stoc: none
  debug2: languages ctos:
  debug2: languages stoc:
  debug2: first_kex_follows 0
  debug2: reserved 0
  debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
  debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
  debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
  debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
  debug3: send packet: type 30
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
  debug3: receive packet: type 31
  debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:serverhostkeyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
  debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts"
  debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts:3
  debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from bitbucket.org
  debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts"
  debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts:11
  debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 104.192.141.1
  debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
  debug1: Found key in /Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts:3
  debug3: send packet: type 21
  debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
  debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
  debug3: receive packet: type 21
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
  debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
  debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
  debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:rsasha256zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
  debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_dsa
  debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa
  debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519
  debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_xmss
  debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
  debug3: send packet: type 5
  debug3: receive packet: type 7
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
  debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com>
  debug3: receive packet: type 6
  debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
  debug3: send packet: type 50
  debug3: receive packet: type 51
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
  debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
  debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
  debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
  debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
  debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
  debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
  debug1: Offering public key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:rsasha256zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
  debug3: send packet: type 50
  debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
  debug3: receive packet: type 60
  debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:rsasha256zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
  debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:rsasha256zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
  debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Comment: did you try to run ```GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -vvv' pip install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/my_org/my_package_repo.git``` to see WHY ssh ignores your key? you can use the same env var to ensure proper key is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log does not show SSH require a password. But a *passphrase* (because the private key was created and then stored encrypted, protected by a passphrase).

That means any `pip install` should be done from a shell where `eval $(ssh-agent); ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` has been executed first, in order to cache said passphrase, and allow the all process to *not* require any input, for an unattended run.

Comment: VonC, any chance you know the answer to this question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70160034/pip-install-custom-package-from-bitbucket-with-ssh-without-entering-ssh-password

Comment: @Jed I did not at first, but I see Ervin did a fine job answering it.