# pip install custom package from BitBucket with SSH without entering SSH password during Docker build

Tags: python, docker, ssh, pip, bitbucket

I'm trying to pip install (via a `conda env create` command) a custom python package from BitBucket during a `docker build` command without entering the SSH password/passphrase. This question is similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70027258/pip-install-custom-package-from-bitbucket-with-ssh-without-entering-ssh-password), but different because the error is occurring during the `docker build` command.

The environment.yml file for the `conda env create` command (during the `docker build`) looks something like this:

```
name: my_app
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - pip=21.2.2
  - python=3.8.11
  - pip:
    - git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/my_org/my_package_repo.git
    - pandas==1.2.5
    - python-dotenv==0.19.0
    - xlrd==2.0.1
prefix: /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/my_app
```

When the `docker build` is trying to build the conda environment inside the Docker image, I get this error:

```
Installing pip dependencies: ...working... Pip subprocess error:
  Running command git clone -q 'ssh://****@bitbucket.org/my_org/my_package_repo.git' /tmp/pip-req-build-3t5mkmnw
  Host key verification failed.
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.
WARNING: Discarding git+ssh://****@bitbucket.org/my_org/my_package_repo.git. Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q 'ssh://****@bitbucket.org/my_org/my_package_repo.git' /tmp/pip-req-build-3t5mkmnw Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q 'ssh://****@bitbucket.org/my_org/my_package_repo.git' /tmp/pip-req-build-3t5mkmnw Check the logs for full command output.

Ran pip subprocess with arguments:
['/opt/conda/envs/work_content/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', '/tmp/condaenv.9p_rq9_h.requirements.txt']
Pip subprocess output:
Collecting git+ssh://****@bitbucket.org/my_org/my_package_repo.git (from -r /tmp/condaenv.9p_rq9_h.requirements.txt (line 3))
  Cloning ssh://****@bitbucket.org/my_org/my_package_repo.git to ./pip-req-build-3t5mkmnw

failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

This remote/custom package installs successfully when I'm in my terminal and follow the answer in the [referenced StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70027258/pip-install-custom-package-from-bitbucket-with-ssh-without-entering-ssh-password).  However, when I try to same thing before running the `docker build` command, I get the error above.  I'm assuming that's because Docker is building a whole new OS image, and it no longer has the SSH RSA passphrase I provided in the terminal.  How can I get past this error without providing the passphrase during the build?

#### Update

Based on suggestions in one of the current answers, I've modified my `Dockerfile` to look something like this:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM continuumio/miniconda3:4.10.3
...
RUN apt-get install -y openssh-client git
RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone git@bitbucket.org:my_org/my_package_repo.git /tmp/my_package_repo
```

The `--mount` command creates a local copy of the repository in the `/tmp` directory.  So now the conda environment.yml file needs to be changed to `pip install` from that local directory like this:

```
name: my_app
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - pip=21.2.2
  - python=3.8.11
  - pip:
    - /tmp/my_package_repo
    - pandas==1.2.5
    - python-dotenv==0.19.0
    - xlrd==2.0.1
prefix: /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/my_app
```

... and I'm running the `docker build` process with commands like these:

```
eval $(ssh-agent); ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --ssh default .
```

The `eval` command above is to manually input my SSH passphrase before the Docker build begins.  The `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` in front of the `docker build` command forces Docker to build with Docker Buildkit which is required for the `RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone` command in the Dockerfile.  This solution works for me now.  It's not exactly what's in the answer below so I thought I'd share this with the community.  I'll be marking the answer that pointed me in this direction as the correct answer.

Comment: You can use a `.netrc` file to autenticate inside your docker container https://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/manual/html_node/The-_002enetrc-file.html

Comment: The `.netrc` file seems promising.  How exactly should I set this up to work with Docker and bitbucket?

Comment: use a `.netrc` is safer than using ssh authentication because you can create token with specific uses granted. You can check https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-oauth-on-bitbucket-cloud/ but github and gitlab also allow create tokens. Then you create your `.netrc` with your token information and connect to your repo by https:/ not using ssh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH needs access to your private RSA key for the authentication. Your private key is not shared with any command which runs inside a Docker image.
Docker has a builtin feature to solve this issue, which is documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds).

Essentially what you want to do is to download your `PUBLIC` key to the Docker image:

```
# Download public key for github.com
RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Define a mount with type `ssh` in order for Docker Engine to forward SSH agent connections.

```
RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone git@github.com:myorg/myproject.git myproject
```

This run command can be something else, for example something which installs your Pythin packages.

You build your docker image with `-ssh` option:

```
docker build --ssh default .
```

Comment: This answer is calling out GitHub, does the same apply for BitBucket?

Comment: Does not really matter if you have GitHub or BitBucket. SSH authentication is the same for both. Also, that line was copied from the Docker documentation. It was just an example, since you don't shave your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: I was able to figure out the solution based the hints provided in this solution.  See the Update in the question for the final solution based on this answer.