# Using a python package stored in private Git Repo for Azure Functions and Container Apps?

Tags: python, azure, github, azure-functions, azure-container-apps

I have a python package in a private GitHub Repo. While using it locally I use

```
pip install git+https://git@github.com/org-name/package-name.git
```

in the bash to install the package.

I want to use that package in my azure functions and container apps. Is there a way to add that package to the requirements file and install it? And what do I need to configure in Github so that my azure resources can access it?

I add git+https://git@github.com/org-name/package-name.git to requirements.txt of the azure function app and I am unable to run it even locally.

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command git clone -q 'https://****@github.com/org-name/packagename.git' 
ERROR: Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a CI/CD pipeline in Azure Devops or github action that :

1. Triggers whenever there is a pull request in github master.
2. Copy the python submodules in azure function and container apps code.

You have to package your code install allow it to be installed using

```
pip install git+ssh://github.com/yourprofile/project.git
```

Comment: Thanks @Anass, if I want to pip install git+https://github.com/yourprofile/project.git will I need any authentication? any access tokens that I need to add to github?

Comment: this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830856/is-it-possible-to-use-pip-to-install-a-package-from-a-private-github-repository

Comment: I was able to use a private package in Azure function using this method. Thanks! I had to do a couple of things in order to achieve it, but the basic idea is the same as you described above.

Comment: @Rebe can you share how you have achieved this?